# Access var of f:selectItem in h:commandButton

Tags: jsf

I want to create a new Bean (child) and add it to an existing Bean (parent), by using `h:selectOneMenu`.

Here is what I come up with. I list up all my existing ParentBeans (stored in ParentBeanStorage) by using `h:selectOneMenu`. All of them are displayed and I can choose one, but it seems like I can't access the `var="pb"` in `h:commandButton` anymore. I get the error: `Target Unreachable, identifier 'pb' resolved to null`.

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>Name:</td>
  <td><h:inputText value="#{childBean.name}" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Parent:</td>
  <td><h:selectOneMenu value="Choose">
    <f:selectItems value="#{parentBean.parentBeanStorage}" var="pb"
     itemValue="#{pb}" itemLabel="#{pb.name}" />
   </h:selectOneMenu></td>
 </tr>
 <h:commandButton action="#pb.addChildBean(childBean)}" />
</table>
```

Why it doesn't work like that and how can I access the choosen Bean in a `h:commandButton`?

Comment: `var = "pb"` is only available in `f:selectItems`, outside it it's null.

Comment: why not use ajax to submit the value of the selection to the server and use that in the action? Way more simple compared to passing parameters around

Comment: @Kukeltje okay so I have to pass my selection like this `<f:ajax event="valueChange" render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
<f:param value="#{id}" name="mySelection"/>` I guess? How can I access the value in the action attribute of the commandButton?

Comment: You access it inside the action that is called from the commandButton, not as a method parameter

Comment: @Kukeltje I don't fully understand. The action is a java method, how can I access the selection from there? If I understand you right, I have to add a listener to my `f:ajax` which sets the selection in a bean (example: `listener="#{controller.setSelection}`) and then do something like this `<h:commandButton action="#controller.addChildToSelection(childBean)}" />`? I am new to this stuff.

Comment: Just separate model (entities/properties) from controller (backing bean). Don't mingle them. Everything will then become straight forward.